# What is the magnetic flux density field of two parallel infinity long conductors with current I and distance a?

Tags: electromagnetism

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_moment#Internal_magnetic_field_of_a_dipole) gives the magnetic flux densities of current loops. The magnetic flux density of two infinitly long conductors look the same, but I am not sure about the numeric accuracy of the value of the field. What is the equation for the field, given the current I and the distance of the conductors a?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Puk already answered you, the resultant magnetic flux density is the superposition of the magnetic flux densities generated by each wire. I'm submitting a new answer because I think that the equation in the Cartesian coordinate system will help the summation.

The magnetic field due to a infinite single wire located at $(x_0,y_0,z)$ is

$$\vec{B}(x,y,z)=\frac{\mu I}{2 \pi [(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2]} [-(y-y_0)\hat{x}+(x-x_0)\hat{y}+(0)\hat{z}]$$

Considering that the wires are crossed by the $y$-axis and the origin has an equal distance from both wires, you may have $+I$ flowing along the wire at $(-a/2,0,z)$ and $-I$ flowing along the wire at $(+a/2,0,z)$.

Comment: Thank you. What does $\hat{x}$, $\hat{y}$ and $\hat{z}$ signify?

Comment: oh, its the unit vector $\hat{\vec{r}}$

Comment: could you please explain where the last term $-(y-y_0)\hat{x} + (x-x_0)\hat{y}$ comes from? I would have expected it to be result of a cross product of the unit vector in current direction $(0,0,i_z)$ and the position vector $\vec{r} = (x - x_0, y - y_0,0)$, but then there would not be any x and y component to the unit vector, right?

Comment: Your cross product calculation doesn't seem right. You may check by yourself at https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cross+product+%280%2C0%2Ciz%29+%28x-x0%2Cy-y0%2C0%29+.

Answer (score 0):

The magnetic field due to a single infinite straight wire has magnitude
$$ B(r) = \frac{\mu I}{2\pi r} $$
where $I$ is the current and $r$ is the distance from the wire. The direction is perpendicular to the axis of the wire and the radial direction, as indicated by the right hand rule. Just add the fields due to the two wires.

Comment: This is a low effort answer. It does not do justice to your reputation score. The grammar, spelling and the equation are correct, though.

Comment: This site doesn't exist to give complete solutions to your homework problems. The magnetic field due to an infinitely long straight wire is one of the simplest problems in electromagnetism. I gave its solution in my answer, and how you can use it to calculate what you want. If adding the two field distributions is too much work for you and you want to be spoonfed the solution, then you are misguided about what this site is for.

Comment: I wont get into an argument with you on here. That is not the purpose of this site, either.